# After upgrading to .NET 4.5, event in UserControl with GridView OnRowCommand with Linkbutton doesn't fire

Tags: asp.net, gridview, .net-4.5

I have a stable application where one function suddenly stopped working, after upgrading from .NET 4 to .NET 4.5. The error has been isolated to an event not firing and it has been confirmed beyond any doubt (on 2 servers and 3 workstations), that this error only happens after the .NET 4.5 upgrade (and did not happen before).

I have the following:

- An empty aspx that only contains a usercontrol (don't ask)
- The user control contains a GridView that is loaded with content after a postback.
- The GridView contains a LinkButton.

  - The Text comes from an Eval
  - It also has an OnDataBinding event that sets the CommandArgument
- The GridView contains an OnRowCommand.

The event in the OnRowCommand is fired in .NET 4.0 and is not fired in .NET 4.5.

Any clues?

**UPDATE**

I simplified my code and got closer to the core of the problem. I found that it was caused by `AllowCustomPaging="True"` on the GridView. After removing this, the postback works fine.

Comment: What's a `OnDataBinding` event? Do you mean `RowDataBound` instead? Does it work without your `UserControl` in an empty page? In general, try to find the core problem by reducing complexity.

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for your suggestion. I did as you suggested, and am updating my question now.

Comment: Do you have any UpdatePanels anywhere ?

Comment: I have no UpdatePanels. Please see updated question.

Comment: Not sure why that caused your issue. However, post it as answer. Maybe it'll help somebody else later.

Comment: @Niels post your update as answer and mark is as accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simplified my code and got closer to the core of the problem. I found that it was caused by AllowCustomPaging="True" on the GridView. After removing this, the postback works fine.

Comment: I would like to understand the issue you faced here. Was your webapp working on 4.0 and just upgrading server to .NET 4.5, it started failing? Or you upgraded your project and re-target to .net 4.5 using Vs2012? GridView on .NET 4.5 has AllowCustomPaging with default value as false. So how did you see allowCustomPaging="True" in your code?

Comment: My webapp was working on 4.0 and I just upgraded the server to 4.5, then it started failing. I did not retarget my application to 4.5 as I expected 4.5 to be completely compatible with 4.0. I had AllowCustomPaging on my GridView as a property in the mark-up. I think this comes from this property having existed in .NET 1.x but I'm not sure.

Comment: AllowCustomPaging has been on DataGrid since 1.1 - probably my GridView was a DataGrid in a previous version. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagrid.allowcustompaging(v=vs.71).aspx