# WebForms GridView row's LinkButton callback not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Yes, another one of these problems I'm afraid.  I do waste a lot of time fixing and refixing finicky callback events in ASP.NET Web Form controls.

This is a page that used to be working but now isn't and I can't see anything relevant that has changed.  I've reduced the page just down to the very basics and added a dummmy datasource to eliminate any possible outside influences.

Despite all of this, it is still not raising the `OnCommand` event of the `LinkButton` controls

I've given it two choices to raise but neither are being called:

1. `OnRowAction` method - referenced from LinKButton control itself via `OnCommand` attribute
2. `OnRowCommand` method - referenced from the `GridView.OnRowCommand` listener.

Here is the code:

```
<%@ Page Title="Completion Report Results" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/PageTemplates/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="CompletionResults.aspx.cs" Inherits="PlatformNET.LRN.Reports.CompletionResults" %>

<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/PageTemplates/Site.Master" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <asp:GridView ID="UserGrid" runat="server"
        AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" GridLines="None"
        DataKeyNames="UserID"
        OnRowCommand="OnRowCommand"
        CssClass="stripey"
        HeaderStyle-CssClass="header"
        PagerStyle-CssClass="footer"
        SortedAscendingHeaderStyle-CssClass="currentsortcolumn"
        SortedDescendingHeaderStyle-CssClass="currentsortcolumn">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action">
                <HeaderStyle CssClass="c" />
                <ItemStyle CssClass="c" />
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="ManageUserLink" runat="server" OnCommand="OnRowAction" CommandName="ManageUser" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("UserID") %>'>Manage</asp:LinkButton>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="TrainingRecLink" runat="server" OnCommand="OnRowAction" CommandName="TrainingRec" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("UserID") %>'>Record</asp:LinkButton>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="UserID" DataField="UserID">
                <HeaderStyle CssClass="c" />
                <ItemStyle CssClass="c" />
            </asp:BoundField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
</asp:Content>
```

Here is the code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Web.Caching;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using AssessmentClassLib.BLL.QueryHelpers;
using AssessmentClassLib.BLL.Reporting;
using AssessmentClassLib.DAL;
using PlatformNET.BLL;
using PlatformNET.CustomControls;
using PlatformNET.LRN.BLL;

namespace PlatformNET.LRN.Reports
{
    public partial class CompletionResults : ReportingPage
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ReportType = "Completion";

            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
                BindGrid();

            base.MakeBreadcrumb(ReportingPageID.completionList);
        }

        internal class DummyItem
        {
            public int UserID { get; set; }
        }

        protected void BindGrid()
        {
            var dummy = new List<DummyItem>();
            for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++)
                dummy.Add(new DummyItem() { UserID = i });

            UserGrid.AllowPaging = true;
            UserGrid.AllowCustomPaging = true;
            UserGrid.VirtualItemCount = 100;
            UserGrid.PageSize = 20;
            UserGrid.PageIndex = 0;
            UserGrid.DataSource = dummy;
            UserGrid.DataBind();
        }

        protected void OnRowAction(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("OnMyCommand(\"{0}\",\"{1}\")", e.CommandName, e.CommandArgument);
        }

        protected void OnRowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("OnRowCommand(\"{0}\",\"{1}\")", e.CommandName, e.CommandArgument);
        }
    }
}
```

Checks done:

1. I am not rebinding the grid on postback (most common novice mistake)
2. The two `LinkButton` controls are not dynamically generated but part of the Cell template
3. The `LinkButton` controls both have `OnCommand` and `CommandArgument` attributes which are populated during the bind (checked by adding a `OnRowDataBound` callback to check during the bind.
4. The generated JS on the link buttons look okay e.g. `<a id="MainContent_UserGrid_ManageUserLink_0" title="Manage User" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$MainContent$UserGrid$ctl02$ManageUserLink','')">Manage</a>`
5. I've set the OnRowCommand attribute of the `GridView` and the function exists in the callback

Please advise on why this very simple example is no longer working.
I am using .NET Framework 4.6.
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to view the request in the network view of your browsers developer tools. It may be returning a useful 500 error.

Comment: I have thanks.  It all looks absolutely fine.
The post goes back and the form data shows:
`_EVENTTARGET:ctl00$MainContent$UserGrid$ctl02$ManageUserLink`.  `_EVENTARGUMENT` exists but appears blank.  Is this expected?  I assume  `_EVENTARGUMENT` isn't required because the row number is encoded in the `_EVENTTARGET`.

Comment: Sorry, another basic question we have to check. How do you know it is not firing? Did you debug through the code behind after the postback happened? Does it go fine through the page_load? Btw, it may be useful to see what happens in ReportingPage's page_load if that exists

Comment: No probs.  I've set a breakpoint on the `Debug.WriteLine()` line of both the `OnRowAction` and `OnRowCommand` methods to see if any get hit.  Debugging is working fine as I also set a breakpoint on `Page_Load` and can step through the binding process (for example) on first call.  The `Page_Load` breakpoint its on callback too but not the `OnRow...` methods.

Comment: Yet another stab - is viewstate disabled anywhere? Clearly not on the page. web.config, master page, base page ReportingPage?

Comment: Thanks @Andrei, yes, I've already checked that.  `ViewState` is `true`.  I've checked visually the page and control html but also checked ViewState of `GridView` at a breakpoint during `PageLoad` or at the binding process.  ViewState is enabled.

However, as the action doesn't fire after page cycles I've lost my virtual data.  Could this be part of the issue?

Comment: I pasted your code in my test project and got the same result (on click: no RowCommand firing, emtpy grid). Then I realized that I had disabled the ViewState at the Master Page level (to test other stuff). After enabling it, everything works.

Comment: Thanks @ConnorsFan, I've checked my Master file but ViewState is enabled there (not explicitly set either way).  I've also checked Web.Config too.

Comment: You may be experiencing the `AllowCustomPaging` problem mentioned in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13742156/after-upgrading-to-net-4-5-event-in-usercontrol-with-gridview-onrowcommand-wit. The event processing suggested in this article could help you to solve it: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.allowcustompaging(v=vs.110).aspx.

Comment: Thanks for the head up on that link @ConnorsFan.  I am setting `AllowCustomPaging` to true and through you might have hit the mark (and maybe you have) however when I tried setting it to false it still didn't work.  
I'm going to update my question as I should be getting ViewState (cell) data back but I'm not.  I'm getting 0 rows whereas before I was.  I think the .NET Framework 4.5 could be the issue.  I'm going to see about targeting 4.0 again

Comment: One way to test if the ViewState is actually activated: (1) add a Label (not a TextBox) and a button outside of the GridView, (2) modify the Label's text in `Page_Load` inside an `if (!IsPostBack)` condition, (3) see the modified text when the page loads the first time, (4) click the button to cause a postback, (5) if the Label's text reverts to its original value (set in markup) after the postback, the ViewState is not activated.

Comment: Good idea @ConnorsFan.  Will try now...

Comment: LinkButtons that render without `href` cause problems - try to avoid them unless you need to render an actual anchor.

Comment: @ConnorsFan, I've added a `Button` and `Label` control and set the Label's text on firsttime load.  It remembers it's state on PostBack so it is definitely localisted to the `GridView` control.

Comment: @ConnorsFan: I converted my assemblies to .NET Framework 4.5 and the problem still occurred.  I tried but failed to convert back to .NET Framework 4.0 but the EF wouldn't have any one it without some major recoding.  I think I was running .NET Framework 4.5 on our last release but that appears to be working on our live system.

Comment: Just curious: if you bind your data on every postback (outside of `if (!IsPostBack)`), does it work? I did that when the ViewState was disabled by mistake during my test and everything worked well.

Comment: @ConnorsFan: I could try that however I'm sure the event won't fire because I will have overwritten the event.  Let me try...

Comment: Okaaaaayy!  So, if I rebind the UserGrid on postback (I might as well anyway as ViewState restored 0 rows on postback) then `OnRowAction` fires!  I thought that rebinding did the opposite - *stopped* events from firing.  So which way is it Microsoft ASP.NET team? and why?  Thansk @ConnorsFan, you could have saved me there.  I would love to know what is going on here as this has affected ALL UserGrid controls out of thin air.

Comment: I "kind of" understand that the data binding must be done on every postback or only on the first page load, depending on the ViewState activation. What I don't understand is why your GridView behaves as if the ViewState is not enabled while it is. Would it make a difference if you set all the GridView properties in markup instead of modifying them in `BindGrid`?

Comment: I'm not sure.  I'm sure if I put data into HTML it would appear on Page Load (not tested though)  However I *do* know that the viewstate used to come back because one of the callbacks (a button on the page) would go through each "row" looking for checkboxes that have been set.  Now (without rebind on post back) `Row.Count = 0`.  I'm going to build a clean ASP.NET Web Forms app and try different GridView options until I have a clear picture.  I am sure it is operating differently from before however. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, I copied your code into one of my Web Forms applications and it worked fine.  I've seen the `eval` statement act finicky in Grids and other repeaters.

Have you tried hard coding the `CommandArgument` value to see if that changes anything?

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, I have hard coded the `CommandArgument` attribute and it still didn't fire.  I assume the actual `CommandArgument`  value is hidden in  `viewstate` during the client cycle as it doesn't show up in the JS.

Comment: That fact that your code worked fine would suggest the issue lies elsewhere?  I'm sure `ViewState` is enabled and certainly the HTML page generated contains a sizable `__VIEWSTATE` field.  However on postback, the event doesn't fire and I don't rebind so I end up with an empty `GridView` (no rows).  Should this happen if `ViewState` is enabled?

Comment: At this point I would suggest creating a new clean web app, which should be fairly easy, and copying over pieces of your web app in there until the issue is reproduced. The cause here is hidden somewhere, and potential places are plenty: master page, web.config, base page class.

Comment: Yes, ViewState does not contain the values for a Grid.  It should be noted that my Web Forms application is Framework 4.0. Did the project get upgraded to 4.6 recently?

Comment: Humm.  I've just used `ildasm.exe` to check the manifest file of the production code: v4.0.30319.  Do you think this might have something to do with it?  I'll need to downgrade and retry but it has dependant assemblies which are also v4.5/v4.6 and I don't know if it will link to them or not.

Comment: I believe all 4.x assemblies will show as v4.0.30319.  I don't have any recent Web Form applications to test that out because I switched to MVC years ago.  I have upgraded many Web Form applications to newer frameworks and always had weird problems.  So I made it a rule to create a new project in the newer framework and copy the code from the older one to the new one.

Comment: @ClintB - According to my tests, and as far as I know, the ViewState does contain the values of the GridView (as also mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5503525/does-gridview-save-data-in-viewstate).

Comment: @ConnsFan - It looks like you're right.  Almost all of my GridViews are populated via UpdatePanel.  I guess that explains why my ViewState doesn't contain the GridView data.